# Localized Gamma Correction

Tags: filters, image-processing, color, pixel-wise-operation

Question:

Is there an algorithm that does (what I would call) "localized" gamma correction?

That is, applying different gamma corrections on different parts of an image, using a masking filter or something along those lines.

I have two images that seem to be correlated by a mix of exposure and gamma corrections, but not equally on the whole image:

First image

[image]

Second image

[image]

For further details on how these images were created, please refer to this (unanswered) [earlier post](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/60233/deriving-transformation-from-input-and-output-images).

Comment: Gamma Correction is Pixel Wise operation So what stopping you from doing it easily?

Comment: I did not mention it in this post, but the images are noisy. Although, I can generate them at any resolution. So, I have a collection of noisy first and second images, and I am trying to figure out what is the transformation from the first to the second image.

Comment: Also, the second image is generated (rendered) at half the lighting intensity of the first image. The solution has to hold for all intensities...

Comment: Could you share few images in full resolution?

Comment: Update: the "local gamma" approach seems to work. I rendered images at various lighting intensities and fitted a gamma curve for each pixel. The family of curves that gamma correction provides seems like a good model, especially for a single stored value.
To filter out some noise, I rendered at a higher resolution (supersampled?) and scaled down. I also clipped the negative (HDR) and very small values to zero and locked the gamma to 1 (linear) for those pixels.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gamma Correction is Pixel Wise operation.
Hence what you can do is estimate it per pixel and then average it per local area.